# how to modify url string of html extension pages

Tags: html

i am asking a very basic question. my problem is that i want to write url string like below

```
http://example.com/index.html/sometext
```

but when i write url like index.html/ it results in page not found. if url only upto index.html then it works. is there any way to write it in html pages. Please help Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The URL you provided is not valid.   The .html extension would be the end of the URL... with the format you've specified, it implies that another folder exists under index.html, which would never be possible.    However, if you want to add parameters to the URL, you can add them like this:

`http://example.com/index.html?text=sometext`

You can then capture that data in your code.

**EDIT**

To answer the second question of how to pickup the URL parameters, you can use the method shown in this post:
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html

Basically, create a function as follows...

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var text = GetURLParameter('text');
```

Comment: thanks this is working but one thing left when i get url string by window.location.pathname in jquery it display only upto .html part. how i get value of text in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You either want to use a QueryString like `http://example.com/index.html&someVar=sometext`

Or you will want to enable [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to transform incoming urls to something that your backend technology understands.

There are lots of frameworks that enable you to use those fancy URLs like `http://example.com/index/someText`, for example [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) for PHP or, ASP.NET MVC, or ...